# What is the amortized time complexity of inserting an element to this structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

Assume you implement a heap using an array and each time the array is full, you copy it to an array double its size. What is the amortized time complexity (for the worst case) of inserting elements into the heap?

I think that we have `T(n) = n * n` (which is an upper bound on the total cost of a sequence of n operations in the worst case), and then the amortized complexity according to one formula is `T(n) / n = n^n / n = n`.

But I think it is very wrong because it is very clear from intuition that I should get `log(n)` or lower ... So how should I calculate this?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why? There is a tag for data-structures here and a lot of similar questions. I think you're mistaken

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that you insert n elements into a heap represented this way. There are two different sources of costs you need to factor in:

1. The cost of the heap operations, ignoring the underlying array resizes.
2. The cost of the array resizes, ignoring the overarching heap operations.

The cost of (1) is O(n log n) across n total operations, since each heap insertion takes time O(log n).

For the cost of (2), notice that the work done to double the size of the array is directly proportional to the size of the array at the time that it's doubled. This means that you'll do 1 unit of work to double the array from size 1, 2 units of work to double the array from size 2, 4 units of work to double the array from size 4, etc. This means that the total work done is

> 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + 2<sup>1 + log n</sup> ≤ 4n - 1 = O(n)

This math uses the fact that you only double the array at most 1 + log n times before it gets up to size n and that 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>k</sup> = 2<sup>k+1</sup> - 1. This means that across all n insertions you do O(n) work doubling the array.

Overall, the total work done across n operations is O(n log n), so the amortized cost per operation is O(log n).

Comment: The only part I don't agree with (or don't understand) is the `<= 4n-1`. Example, initial array size 1, final array size 16.  Items moved 1+2+4+8 = 15. Or initial size 32, final size 256. Items moved 32+64+128 = 224. So it seems like it should be `<= n-1`.

Comment: I understand that the resizing costs O(n). My question is what's the formula for calculating amortized time complexity? And what does amortized time complexity **for the worst case** means?

Comment: @user3386109 Since everything comes out to O(n) anyway, I'm just giving a nice and loose upper-bound.

Comment: @UFCInsider There isn't "a formula" per se. You just add up the total work done across all the operations and divide by the number of operations. The "amortized worst-case" cost would then be the maximum possible amount of work that could be done divided by the number of operations.